# how to unlink Featured Image in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

i have test on site to remove Featured Image from posts

but after that i see img link with post "Uploaded to"

i try find unattach images

[image]

[image]

[image]

in screens post have no img and i cant find it in unattach

only what i want show images that i remove it from posts in unattached in Media Library

Answer (score 0):

I tried to understand how WordPress assigns images to posts, WordPress only does this when the image is uploaded to the post page, and after removing the image from a post, it is not separated, this is a structure in WordPress and there is nothing to worry about.

Comment: that totaly worng i have 50000 img only use in posts 42000 so i have in my media 8000 img not used in posts cuz i remove it from post but the total of images is so big so i want clean my media , how i do that?

Comment: Attributing images to posts is just a tip from WordPress.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).